# androidTest manifest not resolving res

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have `androidTest` folder with a java and a res folder inside, and also the AndroidManifest.xml. In the manifest, I reference e.g. a string from the res folder, but it's marked red. I already set the proper gradle configuration and the tests also run:

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        manifest.srcFile 'androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['androidTest/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['androidTest/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['androidTest/assets']
    }
}
```

Here's part of the manifest:

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="false">
    <activity
        android:name="com.mycompany.test.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @C2H6O I suppose yes, but sadly I don't remember this case anymore. This could have been a false positive caused by another error as it happens many time. Please if you figure it out and remember this post if you could describe your case/solution so others that find this post are helped.